# Ordering sql query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

My sql query gives the columns:

- `product_id` (which is an integer)
- `pnl` (which is float - can be negative)

I get more than 100 rows.

I want to filter out the top 40 rows based on abs(pnl).
But the results should be ordered by pnl column only and not by abs(pnl).

I want to do this for MSSQL 2005.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot do this in a single step / statment. The `TOP x` selection will always be based on the `ORDER BY` ordering instruction. You cannot select the TOP 40 based on `ABS(pnl)` and at the same time order by something else.

What you need to do is a two-step process - either using a CTE (Common Table Expression) or a temporary table - first select the TOP 40 rows ordered by `ABS(pnl)`, then order that result set by `pnl`.

Something like:

```
WITH Top40Rows AS
(
   SELECT TOP 40 product_id, pnl
   ORDER BY ABS(pnl)
)
SELECT product_id, pnl
FROM Top40Rows
ORDER BY pnl
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that product_id is not the primary key of the table, you can do something like this:

```
Select ...
From Table
    Join    (
            Select TOP 40 TablePK
            From Table
            Order by Abs( pnl ) Desc
            ) As Z
        On Table.TablePK = Z.TablePK
Order By Table.pnl ASC
```

As OMG Ponies, mentioned, you could do this as a single derived table:

```
Select ...
From (
        Select TOP 40 .....
        From Table
        Order by Abs( pnl ) Desc
        ) As Z
Order By Z.pnl ASC
```

If you wanted to use a CTE, then I'd do it with the ROW_NUMBER function:

```
With RankedItems As
    (
    Select ...
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Abs(Table.pnl) ) As ItemRank
    From Table
    )
Select 
From RankedItems
Where ItemRank <= 40
Order By pnl ASC
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies - I could do it using a cross join or an exists statement I suppose but an inner join is simpler.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - I suppose I could make the entire TOP operation a derived table which would eliminate the join.

Comment: +1: For the update, but ROW_NUMBER isn't that great of an alternative because it will parse all the table contents.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - By ordering and using TOP against function result, won't that be true anyway?

Comment: My understanding is that such is not the case - it's shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, this is the same as @marc_s, but without using CTE:

```
SELECT product_id, pnl FROM (
    SELECT TOP 40 product_id, pnl FROM tbl ORDER BY abs(pnl) ) x 
ORDER BY pnl
```